# iOS Memory Warnings

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I'm trying to populate a collection view with images downloaded from a Parse database, but I'm receiving memory warnings followed by occasional crashes. Does anyone know how other apps manage to present so many images without crashing? Can someone show me how to optimize what I already have? Here's all the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/sungjp/99ae82dca625f0d73730

```
var imageCache : NSCache = NSCache()


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    self.imageCache.removeAllObjects()
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //In storyboard, my collection view cell has the identifier "PostCell"    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    //I have an array called "posts" that's filled with PFObjects that have UIImage data
    let postings: PFObject = posts[indexPath.row]

    //setting my cell's string property called "objectId" to the PFObject's ID for the purpose of caching shown below
    cell.objectId = postings.objectId! as String

    let theImage: AnyObject = postings["imageFile"] as! PFFile

    if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(postings.objectId!) as? UIImage {

    cell.imageView.image = image
    println("had this photo in cache")

    } else {

        theImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            println("error caching or downloading image")
            return
        }

        let cellImage = UIImage(data:imageData!, scale: 1.0)
        self.imageCache.setObject(cellImage!, forKey: postings.objectId!)
        cell.imageView.image = cellImage
        println("just added another photo to cache")
        }
    }

    return cell
}


class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var objectId: String!

}
```

Comment: I would recommend reading this documentation on tracking memory usage from Apple and tinkering with Instruments to see what, specifically, is eating up your memory. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As @Adrian B said: read about Instruments.
2. You might consider scaling down the images before you save them, or save an additional smaller copy for display in the table view. It depends how good images you need - presumably for the table view not as large as full scale pictures with MB of data. Actually, the images will also look better if they are properly scaled. This by itself should take care of the delays.
3. You have your onw cache strategy, but if you want to improve performance, try SDWebImage (see: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). This library caches images and downloads them asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into scaling down images and SDWebImage. I actually already used the leak instrument, but found no leaks or anything in particular

Comment: This is cool except for the fact that SDWebImage doesn't implement any "cache strategy" regarding to memory cache except for removing all cached objects on memory warnings, which is not how good memory cache is supposed to operate.