# Memory Management On Large Image Collection Apps

Tags: ios, image, caching, memory, sdwebimage

What's the basic idea behind how large apps that contain many images (especially in a table or collection view) manage caching with dequeued cells? No one really answered my previous question about this [iOS Memory Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931592/ios-memory-warnings) and I'm trying to populate a collection view with 100+ images from Parse. After failing to find a good solution with manual code along with down-scaling my images to super low quality, I've tried a number of different libraries, including SDWebImage, LRImageManager, Haneke, and PINRemoteImage. I just want to get a good idea or approach on tackling my app's memory management. How is it that other apps can load hundreds of "fair" quality photos in a dequeue-able view? Is it rocket science?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a combination of things. Don't load all your images in memory at the same time. Save them as files to your documents or caches directory, and load them for each cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and simply discard the in-memory image when the user scrolls it off-screen.

Also, don't load a large image as a thumbnail. Instead, when you download it, immediately generate a thumbnail version at your target display size and save that (**AND** the original version, if you need it.) Then you can load and display the thumbnails, with much lower memory impact. Since you're generating the thumbnails for a particular device, you can generate only the thumbnail size you need (retina or non-retina, sized for the screen on the current device. {iPad/4" phone, 5" phone, iPhone 6, 6+, etc})

Comment: I agree with what all of what you said. I'm using dequeue-able cells, so I'm definitely not downloading all my images at once. I've also immensely improved performance by downscaling my images before uploading them to my Parse database. But when it comes to fetching them from the database, I don't know how of any way to downscale them. I linked my code in the original question, and you can see that I use a cache to hold the images that aren't on the screen. However, I begin to get memory warnings once I start filling the cache (to which I then clear the cache) and my app crashes eventually.

Comment: Don't load your images into a cache. Store them to files on disk, and then load them from each file. That will greatly reduce your memory footprint. As to how to downsample them, create an offscreen graphics context of the correct size, render your image into that target rectangle, and then read a UIImage from the resulting context. See the method `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` in the Xcode docs for more information.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about storing image data to files on disk either. Sounds like a lot of new stuff to learn, but seems useful. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a properly configures memory cache (NSCache, for instance) that would store images resized for their displayed size, which is good for both memory and [drawing performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1708/_index.html). Here's [a tutorial](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager/wiki/Image-Caching-Guide#image-caching-and-nscache) on how to configure NSCache to store images. And that's exactly what [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) does.

```
let targetSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
let request = DFImageRequest(resource: imageURL, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil)
let task = DFImageManager.imageTaskForRequest(request) { (image, _, _, _) -> Void in
    // Image is resized to fill 100x100 px target size
    // Image is stored into mem cache, next request would finish synchronously
    var fetchedImage = image
}.resume()

// NSURLSession stores original data into NSURLCache
```